# Why am I getting a [403] Error when trying to use requests.get in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am new to python and trying to build a data scraper.

When trying to run:

`schedule_data = requests.get('https://nsmmhl.goalline.ca/schedule.php?league_id=264&from_date=2019-09-12&to_date=2020-02-02')`

I get:

`<bound method Response.raise_for_status of <Response [403]>>`

Can anybody tell me why? The link works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the header attribute of the request

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
    'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'
}
schedule_data = requests.get(
    'https://nsmmhl.goalline.ca/schedule.php?league_id=264&from_date=2019-09-12&to_date=2020-02-02',
     headers=headers
)
```

Comment: This worked! Could you tell me why/how I needed to do that? And what to check for in the future if I run into the same problem?